# How to manage dynamic form data using useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a form that gets it's input fields dynamically, it can have hundreds of fields so i can't create a state individually, I was planning on doing something like using an object using the unique key of a form field but need some help.

Suppose the form has fields like this.

```
<form>
 {inputFields.map((i) => {
    <input type={i.type} />
  })}
</form>
```

Now i would need a state like the one below

```
 inputState = {
  "INPUT_FIELD_NAME1": "INPUT FIELD VALUE 1",
  "INPUT_FIELD_NAME2": "INPUT FIELD VALUE 2",
  "INPUT_FIELD_NAME3": "INPUT FIELD VALUE 3",
}
```

I need help with this, how do i set values in such a manner in my input `onChange` and how do i access the values from the state and use them for the matching input field?

Comment: Do you support different input types (text, numeric, true/false) or everything is text-based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding and knowledge, you have to update your dynamic structure like given as below

```
 <form>
    {inputFields.map((i) => (
      <input
        type={i.type}
        name={`INPUT_FIELD_NAME${i.id}`}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    ))}
  </form>
```

Also have to update your react state on input change like

```
const [inputState, setinputState] = useState({});
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setinputState({
    ...inputState,
    [name]: value
  });
};
```

I hope it will work for you! Thanks.

Comment: That works but how do I use that value as a 'value' prop for the input field? value= {inputState.name} will give an error.

Comment: You can set  value like value={inputState?.[`INPUT_FIELD_NAME${i.id}`]}

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({})

const onChange = (event) => {
   const { id, value } = event.target
   setForm((prev) => ({ ...prev, [id]: value }))
}

<form>
   {inputFields.map((i) => {
      <input key={i.id} onChange={onChange} id={i.id} type={i.type} />
   })}
</form>
```

Id must be unique, also you can use "name" property instead of "id"